# evaluating fn in dir-locals.el

Tags: directory-local-variables, eval

I realize there are a number of questions surrounding this topic, but I'm trying use a global function that I've written inside a project `.dir-locals.el`.

Specifically, I wrote a function to add a series of include paths to the `company-clang-arguments` variable. I simply want to call this function (which returns a list of strings), and add it to `company-clang-arguments`.

This is what I am attempting to do:

```
((nil . ((company-clang-arguments . (eval (company-clang-header-paths "/path/to/compile_commands.json"))))))
```

I know that `company-clang-header-paths` correctly returns a list `("-I/path/one -I/path/two")` when I evaluate it in another buffer.

I also know that I am able to use `dir-locals.el` manually like so:

```
((nil . ((company-clang-arguments . ("-I/a/b" "-I/c/d")))))
```

I realize this may be a newbie question, but I'm struggling to understand the evaluation context. The `.` operator cons the list together, but I'm a bit lost on how to evaluate this function and return the list.

I keep running into errors that tell me I'm providing the wrong type:

```
Wrong type argument: stringp, eval
```

Obviously, I've tried playing around, but I always get `Wrong type argument: stringp, <something>`, where `<something>` is the thing I tried.

If anyone could help me out, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Try this `((nil . ((eval . (setq company-clang-arguments (company-clang-header-paths "/path/to/compile_commands.json"))))))`, as `eval` is one of the special variables.

Answer (score 3):

Bearing in mind that .dir-locals.el contains *data*, and forms are not evaluated unless you explicitly say to do so...

```
((nil . ((company-clang-arguments . (eval (company-clang-header-paths "/path/to/compile_commands.json"))))))
```

Sets the buffer-local value of `company-clang-arguments` to the list `(eval (company-clang-header-paths "/path/to/compile_commands.json"))`

Just as if you had used:

```
(setq-local company-clang-arguments '(eval (company-clang-header-paths "/path/to/compile_commands.json"))
```

I presume that `company-clang-arguments` needs to be a list of strings, and therefore the symbol `eval` as the first list item triggers the error you're seeing.  (The second value of that list wouldn't fare any better, but it doesn't get that far.)

To evaluate an expression when the .dir-locals.el file is processed, you need to use the `eval` pseudo-variable. e.g.:

```
((nil . ((eval . (setq-local company-clang-arguments (company-clang-header-paths "/path/to/compile_commands.json"))))))
```